# Is it possible to use the cache I want with @Cacheable spring?

Tags: spring, caching, spring-annotations, spring-cache

I have a custom cache created to suite my application.

I want to use the same for caching remote service calls, it is possible to do the same with @Cacheable?

As far as I explored, I did not find anything which allows @Cacheable to use a custom cache.

Answer (score 2):

Your description of "custom" cache is very vague and can have different meanings depending on the context.

For instance:

1. Do you mean you have built your own caching solution, or perhaps you are using a 3rd party caching solution for which there is no out-of-the-box caching provider implementation provided by either the core Spring Framework [cache storage providers](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-store-configuration) or by 1 of Spring Boots [supported caching providers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_supported_cache_providers)?  If so then you see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-plug).  In a nutshell, you must provide an implementation of Spring's [`CacheManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html) and [`Cache`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html) interface to "adapt" your "custom" caching solution to fit with *Spring's Cache Abstraction*.
2. Or, perhaps you mean you need some complex, rule-based "cache resolution logic" to determine the appropriate cache to use at runtime?  If this is the case, see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-default-cache-resolver).

Let's expand on #1 above, since this seems to be most likely your Use Case.

If you have a self-built, or 3rd party, "custom" caching solution, then of course you must adapt the caching provider's types in order to plugin it into the Spring Framework's caching infrastructure and use [declarative annotation-based caching](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations) (e.g. `@Cacheable`).

It would be unreasonable to expect Spring to know how to interface with ever possible caching implementation available, or yet to be conceived.

So, the `CacheManager` and `Cache` interface allows you to adapt your caching solution/provider of choice, even if you baked it yourself, and still use Spring's caching infrastructure, such as the [declarative annotation-based caching](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations) (i.e. using `@Cacheable`, `@CachePut`, and so on, even [JCache (JSR-107) annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-jsr-107), if you like).

This is the fundamental basis for plugging in and using different caching providers, under-the-hood, in Spring's Cache Abstraction itself.

For example, check out the [Redis implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/tree/2.0.8.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/cache), specifically the [`RedisCacheManager`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/2.0.8.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/RedisCacheManager.java) and the [`RedisCache`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/2.0.8.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/RedisCache.java) classes, which implements Spring's `CacheManager` and `Cache` interfaces, respectively, or the Pivotal GemFire [implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/tree/2.0.8.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/cache) and specifically the [`GemfireCacheManager`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.0.8.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/cache/GemfireCacheManager.java) and [`GemfireCache`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.0.8.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/cache/GemfireCache.java) classes, which again, implements Spring's `CacheManager` and `Cache` interfaces, respectively.

This same pattern is used for all caching solutions, which can possibly be plugged into Spring's Cache Abstraction.

Each caching provider will use a different notion of what the "cache" for that particular provider actually is.  In Pivotal GemFire the cache is a [`Region`](http://gemfire-95-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html).  And so, GemFire's `Region` type must be adapted by implementing Spring's `Cache` interface so that a Region can serve as a "cache" in Spring's Cache Abstraction.  The same is true for any provider, even something as simple as the [`java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-store-configuration-jdk) and then [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/v5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/concurrent).

So, if you have your own cache implementation...

1. First adapt your "custom" cache by implementing the methods in the [`Cache`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html) interface, providing a `CustomCache` class.  The methods in the `Cache` interface will delegate to your actual caching solution.
2. Then provide an implementation of the `CacheManager`, e.g. `CustomCacheManager` that know how to a) configure your caching solution, and b) create instance of `CustomCache` for all the caches identified in Spring's caching annotations.

Let's say you have a `CustomerService` method that know how to find Customers by their `Accounts`...

```
@Service
class CustomerService {

  @Cacheable("Customers")
  Customer findBy(Account account) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then, your `CustomCacheManager` will need to provide a `CustomCache` instance for the "Customers" cache identified in the `@Cacheable` annotation on the `CustomerService.findBy(:Account)` method shown above.

To use your `CustomCacheManager` implementation in your Spring application, then simply declare a bean with a "name" of "cacheManager" that returns an instance of your `CustomCacheManager` class and "enable" Spring's caching infrastructure...

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
class MyCachingConfiguration {

  @Bean
  CustomCacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new CustomCacheManager();
  }
}
```

That's it; you are all set!

Anyway, I hope this helps give you an idea of what you must do.

Cheers!
-John

Answer (score 0):

From Spring docs,

> **Custom cache resolution:** The default cache resolution fits well for
>   applications working with a single CacheManager and with no complex
>   cache resolution requirements.
>
> For applications working with several cache managers, it is possible
>   to set the cacheManager to use per operation:

Refer spring doc [**here**](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.14.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-cache-resolver)

Comment: Cache manager only allows me to return a org.springframework.cache.CacheManager type.. however my custom cache isn't of that type... Even with a cachemanager i am bound to use only spring specific cache it seems..